# integrability of Brownian motion stopped at some stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion starting at zero and denote by $S=(S_t)_{t\ge 0}$ its running maximum, i.e. $S_t=\sup_{0\le s\le t}B_s$. Given a fixed number $p>1$, define the stopping time

$$\tau~~:=~~\inf\Big\{t>0: S_t>\frac{p}{p-1}|B_t|\Big\}.$$

My question is whether we may show that $|B_{\tau}|^p$ is integrable. Thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, isn't $\tau = 0$ almost surely?  It seems to me that the stopping time will occur at least as soon as $S_t > 0$ and $B_t \le 0$, which happens immediately after time 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot for pointing out the mistake. It should be $|B_t|$ in the place of $B_t$.

Comment: But still, for any $t>0$ there is almost surely a zero of Brownian motion in the interval $(0,t]$, so $\tau=0$ almost surely.

Comment: Do you want to start the BM at 1 ?